# Where is bitcoin.conf and why doesn't bitcoind find existing datadir v0.17.1

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin.conf

Just built no gui, no wallet bitcoin on WSL Ubuntu Bionic, Bitcoin v0.17.1.

I want to experiment with bitcoin-cli.

I followed recommendation to run bitcoind -princonsole and it says:
Using config file

> `/home/<myusername>/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

This file doesn't exist.

I followed some dense discussion on how should this behave to make dumb users happier on github, supposedly there were some merges, but frankly, I have no clue what was the final conclusion and what is or isn't in 0.17.1

Eventually, I understood that datadir must be specified first.

But that doesn't work for me.

```
~/bitcoin$ bitcoind -datadir /mnt/d/blockchain -txindex
Error: Specified data directory "" does not exist.
```

/mnt/d/blockchain definitely exists.

Thanks for any help.

Many thanks to **Nate Eldredge** for pointing out a dumb error of mine and hope someone can help parsing and shedding some light on this:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/10746

Blockchain download has started and now I am waiting for the end result.

Comment: Please mark Nate's answer as correct by clicking the checkmark instead of editing your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax should be

```
bitcoind -datadir=/mnt/d/blockchain -txindex
```

Note the `=` sign.

This will look for the `bitcoin.conf` file at `/mnt/d/blockchain/bitcoin.conf` and will store the blockchain, databases, wallet files, etc, all in `/mnt/d/blockchain`.  With this option, Bitcoin Core shouldn't read or write anything in `~/.bitcoin` at all.

Comment: Lol. Feel embarassed. That worked.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu your bitcoin.conf file should be located at `/home/username/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

If that file do not exist create it and fill with standard parameters like:

```
server=1
listen=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=youusername
rpcpassword=yourpassword
rpcallowip=your ip or the rpc commands sending machine
```

Comment: Maybe it should but it isn't:
~/.bitcoin$ ls
banlist.dat  blocks  chainstate  debug.log  fee_estimates.dat  mempool.dat  peers.dat  wallets

Comment: Just type 'touch bitcoin.conf' and fill the file with the aforementioned parameters.